# How to post request?

Tags: express

why is the code outputting an empty `req.body`

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

app.use(express.urlencoded());

app.get("/", (req, res, next) => {
  res.send(`<script>
    fetch("/push", {
        body: "someText",
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "text/html; charset=UTF-8",
        },
        method: "POST",
    }).then((data) => console.log(data));
</script>`);
});

app.post("/push", function (req, res, next) {
  console.log(req.body); //empty here //{}
  res.send(req.body);
});

app.listen(3000);
```

Comment: You have 2 routes: 1) `app.get("/",....` and 2) `app.post("/push",.....`  When is the code outputting an empty req.body ?   Your question should be a [mre]. We should not have to guess if you do a HTTP_GET or a HTTP_POST.

Comment: Do you do your HTTP-Request in Postman or in the browser etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `fetch` statement makes a POST request with `Content-Type: text/html`, which is highly unusual. `express.urlencoded()` does not fill `req.body` for this content type, it is only meant for `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

You can parse arbitrary textual content with code like this:

```js
var body = "";
req.on('data', function(chunk) {
  body += chunk.toString();
})
.on('end', function() {
  res.send(body);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add the `express.urlencoded({ extended: true })` also use the `express.js`

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.json())

app.get("/", (req, res, next) => {
  res.send(`<script>
    fetch("/push", {
      body: "someText",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "text/html; charset=UTF-8",
      },
      method: "POST",
    }).then((data) => console.log(data));
  </script>`);
});

app.post("/push", function (req, res, next) {
  console.log(req.body);
  res.send(req.body);
});

app.listen(3000);
```

Comment: `express.json()` does not handle content type `text/html`.